# android orientation change vertical to right

Tags: android, orientation

My app changes orientation when I move from vertical to the left. But does not when I move from vertical to right?

Comment: Yes, that's the normal behavior.

Comment: Even when I run it on my myTouch phone, it works fine for vertical to left, but does not change orientation for vertical to right...

Comment: That's because that's they way it was built to work. It's not a bug.

Comment: So is this a device specific limitation, or a general Android limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just how Android handles the orientation by default. There are some custom ROMs which have edited the OS to make vertical to right work but this is not common.

Basically, most phones will only ever change where going from vertical to left.

Comment: Just as an update, new HTC Froyo ROMs (On the HTC Desire anyway) support the change or orientation both ways (left and right). Upside-down still doesn't work which is fine. Not certain about other Froyo ROMs

Answer (score 0):

Another update regarding Froyo - Motorola Droid 2 and, most likely, Motorola Droid X also will rotate vertical to right, but not upside down.